# Add JVM parameter to sbt shell configuration in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

I have to set an additional library path `-Djava.library.path=/x/y/z` in order to execute run / debug tasks using SBT, otherwise I get a `NoClassDefFoundError`. Where can I do this in IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add additional parameters in "Settings | Build... | Build Tools | sbt"